# Objective-C constant: Xcode build failure for simulator while success in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, constants

When I build this 2-class simple iOS project in Xcode 5 for iPhoneSimulator, it reports either  "duplicate symbol _FLAG" or "Undefined symbols _TAG", depends on whether I add "Constant.m" in "Build Phases => Compile Sources" or not. But strangely, it builds successfully for a real iPhone(When add Constant.m in compile sources). Could anybody help me out? I really need to debug my project in a simulator(faster). Thanks.

```
Constant.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
const int FLAG = 3;
extern NSString *const TAG;
@interface Constant : NSObject
@end

Constant.m
#import "Constant.h"
NSString *const TAG = @"hello";
@implementation Constant
@end

Deck.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Deck : NSObject
+ (void)sayHi;
@end

Deck.m
#import "Deck.h"
#import "Constant.h"
@implementation Deck
+ (void)sayHi
{
    NSLog(@"%@", TAG);
}
@end
```

Updates:(@trojanfoe)
By `extern` `int`s in Constant.h and define the value for them in Constant.m, fixed the build warning. But in return, many codes like `switch (i) case CONSTANT` does not work. It goes back to `#define`. Any other approaches will be appreciated. Or any explaination of why build for iPhone is Ok and build for simulator is not? Maybe a "get around" for simulator?

[ANSWER](by @trojanfoe)
Using `enum` is a better way to solve the problem. 
My testing:

```
Constant.h
...
enum FlagType {FLAG_A = 0, FLAG_B = 1};
...

Deck.m
...
switch (i) {
  case FLAG_A:
  //do sth...
  break;
}
```

Background Info: I want to include a constant header for multiple class. It contains int and NSString. Though #define works, but it's not a good way to use constant. That's why I'm trying as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `FLAG` as `extern` in the header file and define it in the implementation file (and you don't need to declare/define the `Constant` class at all):

Constant.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
extern const int FLAG;
extern NSString *const TAG;
//@interface Constant : NSObject
//@end
```

Constant.m

```
#import "Constant.h"
const int FLAG = 3;
NSString *const TAG = @"hello";
//@implementation Constant
//@end
```

However you might just as well use a pre-processor constant:

```
#define FLAG 3
```

Comment: Thank you for instant reply. When I try to insert "switch" code in Deck.m in this way, it says "Expression is not an integer constant expression" in line "case FLAG". Can it be fixed? 
`int i = 3;
    switch (i) {
        case FLAG:
            NSLog(@"%@", TAG);
            break;
    }`

Comment: @JoeTse Yes use the pre-processor version `#define FLAG 3`.

Comment: It seems I have to go back with #define for I've used so many `switch` in my code.

Comment: I've tried and I believe `enum` is the best way. Thank you.